How to switch off workspace animations entirely
I've tried the Reduce Motion setting but it still animates, you just get a dissolve instead of a slide.
This is for Mac OS X Sonoma 14.5 (23F79)
Steps to reproduce:

Visit YouTube and play a video
Hit Command + F to enter full-screen
Swipe left with four fingers on the track pad
Swipe right with four fingers on the track pad.
Without Reduce Motion enabled it does a swipe animation.
With Reduce Motion enabled it does a dissolve animation.

The goal is no animation. Ideally across the board for all UI animations.

You could try speeding up the expose (previous name for Mission Control) transition constant, but that’s the opposite of “reduce motion” since it speeds it up - perhaps fast enough you won't see it animating, though

@bmike tx for the suggestion. It made no difference however.

Can you COMPLETELY disable desktop switching animation on macOS?.

Reviewing Apple documentation, I don’t believe that is a feature you can toggle in settings.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/stop-or-reduce-onscreen-motion-mchlc03f57a1/mac

It lists just three items, none of which are for Mission Control, Stage Manager, window resizing / zoom or full screen transitions. Perhaps someone has an update for these “undocumented” preferences. Many report they are less effective than in the past or just not implemented behind the scenes.
